# Public Google drive image url display on webpage

Tags: css, image, background, google-drive-api

(I'm a novice programmer so apologies if this seems like simple stuff!)

I want to get an image hosted on my google drive to appear on a webpage I'm trying to build. At first it works (by taking the image URL from 'open image in new tab'), but then it will stop working after a few days. I'll put the URL into my browser and the image isn't there any more.

I saw the advice here: http://googlesystem.blogspot.fr/2013/02/permalinks-for-google-drive-images.html
So I tried to make a permalink, but neither of the image urls (shareable link, or actual image url) had "docs.google.com/file/d/FILEID/edit" at the beginning. I've tried replacing what they did have there, but that didn't work either.

The image is set to public, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Here is the image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P2uxQ0jyUMZ2N6YmkxR0oyU0U/view?usp=sharing

I've been pasting the urls into the CSS as 
body {
    background: url(LINK);

Thanks in advance! Tom